# Fastest way to calculate an inner product of binary vectors in numpy

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy, vector

So I have `X` and `Y` which are binary vectors of the two elements 0,1, and are about 30000 elements long. What I want to do exactly is find a fast way to calculate `np.inner(X, Y)/np.sum(Y)`. I don't think much can be done about the `np.sum(Y)` part, which basically just counts how many 1s there are in `Y`. The `np.inner(X,Y)` part actually counts the number of 1s in `X` whose corresponding element (i.e. same index) in `Y` is also 1, i.e. it works out the same as

```
re = 0
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    if X[i]==1 and Y[i]==1:
       re += 1
return re
```

I think `np.inner` is the most straightforward way and also the fastest way I can think about within `numpy`. However the performance is still not satisfactory: this calculation makes up most of the computational cost of a function that has to be iterated hundreds of times, and the total runtime turns out as long as 90s. So I've been thinking quite hard about optimising it. I tried using `X @ Y.T`, which didn't make much difference unsurprisingly. I also checked that my `numpy` package is linked to all the common optimising packages like `blas` or `mkl` etc (the only one unavailalbe is `openblas`). Anyway is there any possible room for speeding up this calculation?

Comment: @DYZ I'm afraid `(x==y)` would create a Boolean matrix rather than a Boolean vector?

Comment: `(X&Y).sum()` correctly calculates `np.inner(X,Y)` of `X` and `Y` as long as both contain only 0s or 1s.

Comment: As I said, it correctly calculates `np.inner(X,Y)` (why don't you give it a try?) However, it seems to perform slower than `np.inner(X,Y)`. Apparently, the function has the optimal performance.

Comment: @DYZ thanks for the suggestion. Yeah according to my test just now it doesn't seem to be faster than `inner`. I probably have to optimise elsewhere.

Comment: @PaulPanzer they are originally `float32` but don't have a regular distribution.

Comment: @Vim seems I have to correct myself. With `float32` and your array size `np.count_nonzero` appears to be substantially slower than sum :(

Comment: @PaulPanzer this shouldn't be a problem, because I can convert it to int beforehand.

Comment: @PaulPanzer nevertheless, I don't think `np.count_nonzero` can yield the result in one go.

Comment: @Vim the main factor appears to be the data size. Apparently sum has a huge overhead but then runs extremely fast. I made a quick benchmark and if I didn't make some stupid mistake then for array sizes `100, 1000, 10000, 100000` with `float64` it takes `2.8 us, 3.5 us, 7.6 us, 45 us`. Unless you give `count_nonzero` its favourite (`bool`) it can't compete at the large array sizes. And whatever you gain you will lose again because the inner product is fastest with `float` dtypes.

Comment: On my setup, the performance increase when using floats is only pronounced when using multiple threads (with numpy linked against openblas).